# Oauth state storage

Tags: oauth, state, openid-connect

I want to implement OAuth Authorization Code flow.I have a problem with storing state. I'm implementing Auth Server, Resource Servers and the Clients.
What i know is that when the client performs redirect to Auth Server's login form it should send state aswell.
So my Auth Server get 'state' and sends back login html page.
Now after User's credentials will be verified with success, Auth Server should redirect User-Agent to given redirect_uri in the request with 'state' given by the client within request to the login page.

1. How do my Auth Server know which 'state' should be returned to which Client ? Becouse i have 'state' from Client after first request and then i'm returning html login page. Then User is submitting this form with its credentials and then redirect happens. So how do i store 'state' to match. Where is 'state' between request and credential submit ? How do i store it that later i know it should be returned to particular redirect_uri?

Answer (score 1):

You should return the same state value that you received in the initial authentication request back to the client.

You can for example store the initial state value in a session cookie with each user; by using this technique, you can keep track of the state.

I recently blogged about this topic:

- [Demystifying OpenID Connect’s State an
  Nonce Parameters in ASP.NET Core](https://nestenius.se/2023/12/13/demystifying-openid-connects-state-and-nonce-parameters-in-asp-net-core/)

Comment: You mean if i receive get request with all this variables (request_uri, state, client_id etc.) i should return login form with cookie contains state value ? Then when user submits the form i should inspect this cookie and redirect user with state query parameter from this cookie ? Is it safe approach to store state on the browser ?

Comment: Yes, using cookies is safe if you properly secure it using HttpOnly, SameSite, and the Secure attribute. In many platforms, the cookie is also encrypted (like ASP.NET Core). When you sign in with OIDC, you typically establish a cookie-based user-session. One session with the identity provider and one with the client asking for tokens.